# Is Chrome on Ubuntu incorrectly calculating fractional percent-based CSS widths for Twitter Bootstrap layouts?

Tags: css, google-chrome, ubuntu, twitter-bootstrap

I use Twitter Bootstrap for a variety of projects.

All used to be fine and then, out of the blue (most likely following a Chrome update a couple of months ago), all layout hell broke lose when viewing in Chrome on Ubuntu for development.

My layouts using the Twitter Bootstrap grid system used to be so lovely. And then they weren't, with the right-most column dropping down below its siblings.

Twitter Bootstrap fluid layouts use percent-based widths, such as this from 2.3.2:

```
.row-fluid .span4 {
  width: 31.623931623931625%;
  *width: 31.570740134569924%;
}
```

Awesome!

Well, almost awesome.

Things render nicely on Chrome in Windows, on my Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 but not on Chrome in Ubuntu. I don't believe this to be a Ubuntu-specific thing (such as oddly-sized typefaces) as things are just perfect in Firefox.

Here's one of the example grid layouts rendered under Chrome 28 on 12.10:

[image]

And the same under Firefox 18 on the same machine:

[image]

I can fix this for my own sites (and have done). But it's somewhat bothersome for other Bootstrap-based sites that I view on my main Ubuntu machine under Chrome.

The questions:

- Am I going mad (aka is is just me)?
- Are there any settings in Chrome I should examine so that I can have Bootstrap-based layouts work like they do for the rest of the known world?

Comment: Check the window.innerWidth property and see if they're coming out different.

Comment: looks fine for me in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in chrome 28. http://cl.austin.pe/image/3N0K3j3q0D3H

Disable all your plugins.

Comment: no problem in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Google Chrome 28.0.1500.63 for me

Comment: Great, just me then! That's relieving to know.